# C++ enable_if (or workaround) for member operator

Tags: c++, templates, operators, type-traits

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    T* p;
    foo(T* x) : p(x) {}
    ~foo() { if(p) delete p; }
    T& operator*() const { return *p; }
};

int main()
{
    foo<int>  i(new int);
    foo<void> v(new int);   // <= illegal use of type 'void'
}
```

If T = void then I don't want to implement the operator*(). How can I achieve this? I don't want to specialize the class, because there are many other methods in my class.

PS: Please note that this is just an example to explain my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++11 standard solved this for `std::unique_ptr` like so:

```
typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type
    operator*() const { return *p; }
```

Comment: Hum, I could use this in C++, too: typename std::add_reference<T>::type operator* () const { return *p; }

Answer (score 6):

You can move all the other methods (which play well with `T==void`) into a base class and make `foo` derive from it. Then `foo` can be specialized to not declare the `operator*` for `T==void`

```
template <typename T>
struct foobase {

  T* p;
  foobase(T* x) : p(x) {}
  ~foobase() { if(p) delete p; }

};

template <typename T>
struct foo : foobase<T> {
  T& operator*() const { return *p; }
};

template<> 
struct foo<void> : foobase<void> {

};
```

Answer (score 3):

Like that:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo_base
{
    T* p;
    foo(T* x) : p(x) {}
    ~foo() { if(p) delete p; }

    // other methods …
};

template<typename T>
struct foo : foo_base<T>
{
    T& operator*() const { return *p; }
};

template<>
struct foo<void> : foo_base<void>
{
};
```

Comment: (+1) Interestingly, while I was adding a code sample to my initial response it seems that we overlapped a bit, except I chose `foobase` rather than `foo_base`. Oh well.. :-)

Comment: @Alexander I didn't gave an additional explaining :( but my code formatting is nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
typename disable_if<is_void<T>, T>::type& operator* () const { return *p;}
```

or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: `disable_if` but otherwise I agree.

Comment: That doesn't work, because when 'T = void', then 'T&' is not legal: 'abstract declarator' : illegal use of type 'void'

Comment: SFINAE only works for template functions, i.e. it doesn't work for non-templated member functions of templated classes like in this case. You could also template the member function and check for the type being the same as `T` but that wouldn't be exactly elegant.

Answer (score 0):

What's about this solution:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    T* p;
    foo(T* x) : p(x) {}
    ~foo() { if(p) delete p; }

    template<typename U> struct impl { U& deref(U* p) { return *p; } };
    template<> struct impl<void> { void deref(void* p) { } };

    typename boost::conditional<std::is_void<T>::value, T, typename std::add_reference<T>::type>::type operator*() const
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_void<T>::value, "illegal use of type 'void'");
        return impl<T>().deref(p); 
    }
};
```